# POJO with array of integers to deserialize

Tags: java, android, gson

I am having some trouble deserializing the following **JSON** into a **POJO**. I have no control over the **JSON** structure, else I would've implemented it in some other way, but, that's life for you.

```
{
    "1":{
       "test":"1",
       "other":"stuff"
   },
   "2":{
      "test":"2",
      "other":"stuff2"
   }
}
```

Anyway, I am trying to deserialize by using a POJO with:

```
public Map<Integer, Payload> payload;
```

but although the Map does have a size of 2, when I try to get each of it, it's contents are *null*. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try ```Map<String, Payload>``` ? That's the correct JSON structure.

Comment: @danypata, yeah I have. Same outcome.

Comment: Can you add the code for the POJO and the parsing code.

Comment: I feel so dumb right. The problem was the way I was retrieving the data from the Map, as I was doing something like .get(1) instead .get("1") and I was getting away with it, as it expects an Object (of course). damn it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how the payload class looks like, but it should be something like this:

```
class Payload {
    String test;
    String other;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Payload [test=" + test + ", other=" + other + "]";
    }
}
```

If you assert this condition, then you can deserialize the json using a TypeToken> as token as  **danypata** suggest... like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
String ff = "{\"1\":{" + "\"test\":\"1\"," + "\"other\":\"stuff\"" + "}," + "\"2\":{" + "\"test\":\"2\","
    + "\"other\":\"stuff2\"" + "}}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Payload>>() {
}.getType();
Map<String, Payload> map = gson.fromJson(ff, mapType);
System.out.println(map);
for (Entry<String, Payload> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
}
```

giving as result:

> {1=Payload [test=1, other=stuff], 2=Payload [test=2, other=stuff2]}
>
> 1
>   Payload [test=1, other=stuff]
>
> 2 
>   Payload [test=2, other=stuff2]

Comment: thank you. I did have everything well implemented, it was just the way I was getting the values from the Map that was being asinine. I do not use TypeToken though, and the Pojo can map everything out currently. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [Android JSONObject class](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)? Then you can parse with it your entire JSON string and then you can obtain the values easily. For example this is to get the values of your "1" JSON object:

```
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    final String test = jsonObject.getJSONObject("1").getString("test");
    final String other = jsonObject.getJSONObject("1").getString("other");
```

Comment: hi. I have the problem solved, I was just being dumb when retrieving the data from the Map. The problem with your solution (it's easy to fix it), would be that the the you could have N arrays, and that would you would be limited.

Comment: The JSONObject object can contain multiple JSON like objects. One of these is the JSONArray object. It let you search the content with an standard array like interface (index number, lenght, etc.).

Comment: yeah, sure... I like the Gson way, and I sticking to it :)